# Code completion not recognizing members from OpenLayers js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, resharper, intellisense

I have a Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET MVC 4 project. In a view, I'm importing the [OpenLayers.js](http://openlayers.org/) file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

below, I have an inline script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init()
    {
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
        var osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(/* constructor params */);
    }
</script>
```

How can I get Visual Studio / ReSharper IntelliSense to suggest property and method names like this:

```
osmLayer.w   // should suggest osmLayer.wrapDataLine
osmLayer.att // should suggest osmLayer.attribution
```

Oddly, it suggests members defined by JQuery: `constructor`, `prototype` and `length` all appear in the completion dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, ReSharper's javascript intellisense is not perfect and currently doesn't support non-standard JS class frameworks such as the one used by OpenLayers. We plan to address this in future versions. In the mean time, if you have to use such libraries, you can either use non-smart intellisense by pressing Ctrl-Space or try to use Visual Studio built-in intellisense (go to ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Intellisense | General, select "Limited ReSharper Intellisense" and turn off JavaScript).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried this, but Visual Studio IntelliSense doesn't offer any more autocomplete options than ReSharper does... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, maybe Visual Studio requires correct references directives, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682(v=vs.110).aspx#ReferenceDirectives . But it could be the case that VS also doesn't support your case. Implementing intellisense for a dynamic language such as JS is difficult. Anyway, with ReSharper you can always manually press Ctrl-Space and get all possible JS properties.